# PHP - Set auction end date to end in a weekday

Tags: php, datetime

I'm making an auction house where the auction ends after 1 month of the date it started.

Here's what i got so far:

```
$added_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ends_on = new DateTime('NOW');
$ends_on->add(new DateInterval('P1M')); // 1 month
$ends_on->format('U');
$stringdate = $ends_on->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I need the auction to end 1 month after but on a week day, if possible, between 9h-18h. Any idea how to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the day number of the new `$ends_on` date i.e. `$d = $ends_on->format("w");` If 0 (Sunday) add 1 more day. If 6 (Saturday) add 2 more days. The times will need a bit more as when do you decide the cut off time. If a entry is made after 1800 does it still expire on the same day or the next day?

Comment: It would have to be the following day, Jeff

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion and it works.

This will show a date that will go to the following monday if it lands on the weekend.

Any idea how to sort the time too? :)

Comment: Also, it could have a fixed hour, say, every auction would have to end at 14h. It's probably simpler to do this instead.

Comment: I got the hour to be set at a specific time, thank you for steering me in the right direction, @jeff